# Angular 13: 415 Error Unsupported Media Type, on Delete

Tags: html, mysql, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

my Services.ts

```
deteleComentario(id: number): Observable<any>{
return this.http.delete(this.myAppUrl + this.myApiUrl + id);
```

}

my list-Comment-Component.ts

```
eliminarComentario(id: any ){
this.comentarioService.deteleComentario(id).subscribe(data => {
  this.getComentarios();
  
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
}

);
```

}

And my Api, NetCore with Mysql it`s work fine in GET, POST, GET{ID}, PUT{ID}, DELETE{ID}
any suggestion what could be the problem

[image]

Comment: You have to show an API action too

Comment: what type is "this.http" ?

Comment: You need to check if your data passed to api is right for 415 error.

Answer (score 2):

The **415 Unsupported Media Type** is a **client-side error** that indicates the request entity has a media type that the server or resource does not support. The response code may still be returned if the contents of the request body were not supported by the server. For example, a server might support specific JSON bodies, but the payload contents didn't validate, perhaps because it was missing a required property.

For example, the client uploads an image that was not in one of the formats (e.g., JPEG, PNG), or a video that is not in an accepted format (e.g., MPEG). The best way to fix it is to remove the image or video and upload a file in one of those formats.

Please see [documentation](https://www.exai.com/blog/415-unsupported-media-type) for more information.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).